# How to transform attribute values into keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON in the format.

```
var input = [
{status:"good", state: "NY"},
{status:"bad", state: "FL"},
{status:"decent", state: "CA"}
]
```

I want to transform it in an object of the format:

```
myObj = {NY:"good",FL:"bad",CA:"decent"}
```

The reason I want this is so that I can easily grab the myObj.NY value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and simple

```js
var input = [
  {status:"good", state: "NY"},
  {status:"bad", state: "FL"},
  {status:"decent", state: "CA"}
]
var obj = {};
input.forEach(function(k) {
  obj[k.state] = k.status;
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myobj = {}; 
Input.forEach(function (i) { myobj[i.status] = i.state;}
```

Comment: `Input.foreach` should be `input.forEach`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using "Object.assign" and "Array.map" as well like below to achieve your desired result

```js
var input = [
{status:"good", state: "NY"},
{status:"bad", state: "FL"},
{status:"decent", state: "CA"}
]

let res = Object.assign(...input.map(({ state, status}) => ({ [state]: status })))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple `forEach()` loop on that array with array destructuring to make your code short and simple.

```js
var input = [{
    status: "good",
    state: "NY"
  },
  {
    status: "bad",
    state: "FL"
  },
  {
    status: "decent",
    state: "CA"
  }
];
var res = {};
input.forEach(({state, status})=> res[state] = status);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```
var myObj = input.reduce( (r,x) => { r[x.status] = x.state ; return r }, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished as well using `map`, by assigning the object key through the `[key]` syntax:

```
var input = [
{status:"good", state: "NY"},
{status:"bad", state: "FL"},
{status:"decent", state: "CA"}
]
var myObj = Object.assign({}, ...input.map(item => ({
    [item.state]: item.status
})));
console.log(myObj);
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/gL6bcqm1/1/

Comment: `myObj` will be an array of objects, not a single object. Also using `Object.assign` here is unnecessary.

Comment: Wops, sorry, misunderstood the question. Thanks for pointing that!